# Restoring default Outlook email directory structure

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, pst

I am using 2007 Outlook and Comcast is my email provider.  Don't know if it matters, but my wife and I are probably the only people who still do this, but have a common email which is used on two PCs.  I rebuilt Windows from scratch, reinstalled Outlook, and moved over my pst file.  But things are not just right.

See my below folder structure (blanks represent personal folders which I didn't want displayed).  New emails are displayed under the second Inbox under the email account. If I delete an email, it doesn't disappear, but stays in the inbox but with a line through it.  If I click on the email in the directory tree, it displays "Cannot display the folder. This is the root of an IMAP store.  The root does not contain messages but may have subfolders that do.  To see messages in the subfolder, display the folder list and then click the subfolder."

How do I get it back to normal?  I want to keep my old emails and various personal folders, but don't want multiple inboxes, etc.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Possibly you copied an extremely large folder without setting Outlook to "work offline" which means it would have likely started to sync while still in a heavy "copy" process overlapping with the send/receive process. Try to start from scratch while putting Outlook offline (on the send/receive tab click on the Work Offline Box so that the box itself is highlighted).

Comment: "How do I get it back to normal?" This is the Default (=normal) behaviour. "I want to keep my old emails and various personal folders, but don't want multiple inboxes, etc." Then just don't use PST-Files, just use your IMAP Account.

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1

**First You have select Work Offline**

[image]

Click on the Work Offline. So mail flow will Stop.

**Later Go To Tools and Account Settings. In Data Tab**

[image]

Which Data Files you want to set as Default.
In your Case. @comcast.net **set as default** click on OK and Then in Outlook Copy Manually (Drag and Drop) the all folder From Personal Folder to @comcast.net.

Once all mails are moved to @comcast. Go to Tools and Account Setting. In that Data Files Tab. Delete the Personal Folders. Keep only One PST of @comcast. Remember to Un-tick Work Offline.

### Step 2

**Otherwise If you are sure that Mails which has come to @comcast.net will receive again then you can re-configure the account. Make sure its in Offline Mode.**
**Once configuration done, again it will create new PST. You have Mount the older PST and Change the Folder as image given below.**

[image]

- Go to Tools and Account Setting.
- Select the Active account.
- Click on Change Folder.
- Select The OLD PST. Which you mounted. Click on OK.
- Remove the New PST later from DATA FILES

**Remove the Work Offline, So the mail received will Go to your Old PST**

### Step 3

*As per the discussion in Chat with OP*

**You can't change the default delivery folders of IMAP accounts. They have their own PST files and they use a preset folder structure in that PST file. You can create a new PST file, but it's going to be the same deal - only Inbox. Best you can do is create a rule to move messages from Inbox to old pst as you desire**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59636/discussion-on-answer-by-techie-gossip-restoring-default-outlook-email-directory).